# This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in AppName.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded

Tags: c++

Recently, I've tried to execute my C++ app which I've developped 2 weeks ago. So, I'm getting these two errors while debugging it:

The first is:

> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in
>   AppName.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

And, the second is:

> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I can't post my code, because it's too long. I'm just asking for explanation to these two errors and why they have suddenly appeared. Knowing that the first posted error isn't always displayed and triggers by different instructions once per execution and that the second one is displayed on the marked line:

```
CCriticalSection m_csOK;
CSingleLock lock(&m_csOK, TRUE); //the marked line
```

Thanks a lot!!